# I have an array of elements.Want to break into group with the first value as the key.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Below is the array which contains 8 elements .i want to break this into a group of first 4 then 4 and next 4 and so on if it contains more elements.I want to do this using javascript or jquery. need help

```
["30", "1", "asad", "23", "31", "1", "amit", "45"]
```

Want to Break into this format

```
[30]=>['30','1','asad,'23'']    
[31]=>['31','1','amit','45']
```

after getting these comma separated values how to store that in php variable so as to 
insert multiple values one after the other.

Comment: have you tried something so far????

Comment: @Kartikeya have tried with the slice method but no luck

Comment: post the code you have tried..

Comment: Will there always be multiples of 4?

Comment: @Kartikeya i have tried this much only but dont know what to do forward.New to javascript. var newarr=textBoxValues.slice(0,4).help me if possible?

Comment: @curious2lrn why do you want the first item as key?

Comment: @AmitJoki it's a college project i am making bus bookink online.so i would like to categorize it seat wise which is the first value

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there will always be multiples of 4 elements, create an object, loop over the array elements and populate each key/value:

```
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l;  i+=4) {
  obj[arr[i]] = [arr[i], arr[i+1], arr[i+2], arr[i+3]];
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2hoqham/)

I don't use PHP so I can't help with the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ary = ["30", "1", "asad", "23", "31", "1", "amit", "45"];
var ret = {};
for(var i = 0; i < ary.length; i+=4) {
    ret[ary[i]] = ary.slice(i, i+4);
}

ret; // {"30": ["30", "1", "asad", "23"], "31": ["31", "1", "amit", "45"]}
```

Comment: could you help me with the second part of how to store that in php variable

Comment: JS is executed at client side. You want to store in PHP, you need to send request to server.

Comment: my php and javascript are on the same page

Comment: where are the data come from? user input, or originally from server?

Comment: data is being dynamically generated

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by splicing the array using [`Array.splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```
var result = {};
while(arr.length > 0) { var rmd = arr.splice(0, 4); result[rmd[0]] = rmd; }
```

You can check the content of `result` by `console.log(result);`

Comment: how to store that in php variable.how to multiple insert

Comment: @curious2lrn I'm not a php guy, so sorry